# Recommended error monitoring / exception logging platforms or solutions

Tags: logging, monitoring, error-logging, health-monitoring, exception-logging

I'm working with a group of students on a web application built with ASP.NET Core and Angular.

The project is going in production in the near future, but before we go live we want a error monitoring / exception logging solution. I did some research online and found many options:

- Sentry
- StackExchange Exceptional
- Rollbar
- Raygun
- Bugsnag
- LogRocket
- Airbrake
- Azure Application Insights

I've been struggling to get a clear picture of which solution is most popular or recommended for production environments.

My question is: what error monitoring solution, if any, have you used and/or are using in a production environment in which you participated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bugsnag has native support for both [ASP.NET Core](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/dotnet/asp-net-core/) and [Angular](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/javascript/angular/). The simplicity of integration, configuration, and usability qualifies as one of the better options for error monitoring.